# How to save a fileupload to a viewstate after postback?

Tags: asp.net

I have a FileUpload and multy control on page. All controls are located inside the updatepanel other than FileUpload.

After post back, i save fileupload in a viewstate.

```
private FileUpload Files
{
    get { return (FileUpload)ViewState["Files"]; }
    set {
        ViewState["Files"] = value;
    }
}


.
.
.
if (ImageFileUpload.HasFile)
 {
    Files = ImageFileUpload;
 }
```

But i get error

> Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is - this can't be done...
When you get a postback with a FileUpload you ***must*** save it (or do whatever you want) at that point. You ***can't*** keep the stream for the following postbacks.

What you *can* do is:

1. Save the file to the server.
2. Add the filename to the ViewState so you can locally access the file later on.

In other words, something like this:

```
string filename;
......
// Save file to disk
fileUpload1.SaveAs(filename);
// Keep path to file in ViewState
ViewState["FileLocation"] = filename;
```

Comment: Thanks, i want save file when savebutton click. but i have a dropdownlist that autopostback is true. when i change dropdownlist fileuplad was empty, i want save fileupload and in savebutton save it.

Comment: Sounds like a UX problem, to solve the problem that someone might first select the file and then change the dropdown - Make the `FileUpload1.Visible = false` until AFTER the dropdown is changed. Only when the dropdown is changed make the `FileUpload1.Visible = true`

Comment: i have multy dropdownlist that user change it. I want save fileupload after first postback. It is possible???!!

Comment: @Niloo - Yes, you can save the file by checking if the `HasFile` property is `true` (in `Page_Load`). It ***should*** still be true if you selected a file and then did an AutoPostback. If it is not true, you have something else (like an UpdatePanel) which is causing problems...

Comment: thanks, but i want to save file when savebutton click, i don't save file in post back!.

Comment: I'm trying to explain - you don't have a choice... You will only have ***one chance*** to save the file, it will be on the *first postback* after user selected the file...

Comment: @Blachshma Then how to return the value on the PageLoad FileUpload control?